# Displaying images from react-native-fetch-blob?

Tags: react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

My goal is to be able to cache images with react-native-fetch-blob. My problem is trying to read the source of a react-native-fetch-blob path within a React Native Image component. Nothing shows up on the screen and I've looked at several stack overflow and github issues and questions, but I can't find the solution. This is for Android.

I believe I am able to store my images in a file directory correctly. I'm running the storeImages() code below and it has a RNFetchBlob.fs.exists() method, which is returning true when checking the file path. The code below is being ran inside my redux file within another API call. It's taking information from a redux object to store the image according to it's schedule_id value.

***storeImages()*** in Redux

```
function storeImages(obj){
    let picDir = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.PictureDir;
    //Run first for the Card Image
    RNFetchBlob.config({
        fileCache : true,
        //is appendExt necessary? I tried both and nothing displayed
        // appendExt : 'jpg',
        path: ${picDir}/${obj.schedule_id}BG
        })
        .fetch('GET', `${obj.cardImage}`, {
        })
        .then((res) => {
            let status = res.info().status;
            RNFetchBlob.fs.exists(res.path())
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
            })
            if(status == 200) {
            // the temp file path
            console.log('The file saved to ', res.path())
        }
        })
    .catch((errorMessage, statusCode) => {
        console.log(errorMessage);
    })
```

I'm importing React Native Fetch Blob in my component also and then using the same image path, and the schedule ID in the string is coming from the container component. Since it is an API call that saves the image, I use RNFetchBlob.fs.exists() to see if the file has been stored. This returns true and displays the image in the source attribute. I use uri, because the image path is dynamically created.

***render()*** in my component

```
render() {
    let picDir = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.PictureDir;
    let imgPath= `${picDir}/${this.props.assetData[0].schedule_id}BG`;

    return(
        // Max height and width of screen
        <View style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, height, width, zIndex: 1 }}>
            {
            RNFetchBlob.fs.exists(${picDir}/{${this.props.assetData[0].schedule_id}BG) 
            ?
                <Image source={{ uri: imgPath}} resizeMode='cover' style={{flex: 1}} />
            :
                null
            }
        </View>
    )
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions for me.

Comment: What is **BG**?             *RNFetchBlob.fs.exists(${picDir}/{${this.props.assetData[0].schedule_id}BG)*

Comment: @HoàngVũAnh I add it to the string, because everything in assetData comes with a background(BG) image and card image. I do something seperate for card images. Overall goal is to cache images from a URL link. I'll add the goal to my description also..